# How to store two dimension array of string in Elixir Ecto. How to put matching length to list?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How do I save 2d lists into postgres?
Or put matching lengths to lists?

I tried this in my migration..

```
  add :checkpoints, {:array, :string}
```

and schema..

```
  field :checkpoints, {:array, {:array, :string}}
```

But when i save this sample value of `[["C23", "E12"], ["N34"], ["G22"]]` to :checkpoints field,
I get this error:

```
(ArgumentError) nested lists must have lists with matching lengths
```

Comment: It's not Ecto problem at all, the error comes from PG itself - it requires multidimensional arrays to have matching extents for each dimension...

Comment: As a workaround (kind of) you could try using json(b) which is less restrictive. There is a tradeoff though - bizarre syntax which makes queries ugly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of our lists need to have the same length. Your first list has three elements, the other ones have only 1.